# iPhone to Flash porting

Tags: iphone, c, flash

I need to port an existing game written for the iPhone to Flash. The iPhone game is mainly written in pure C rather than Objective C.

I'm wondering if there are any good tools for converting the C code to Actionscript directly, or in general if anyone has some advice on how to do this porting in an efficient way given its C based source code?

Since the game will keep getting updated with bugfixes etc, a method allowing rapid conversion of the updated game code to Flash so that only one code base would need to be maintained would be optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/).  This might be what you want, but I suspect you will have issues simply compiling on different compilers since the user-input differs immensely between a flash game and an iphone game.

Comment: Yes, there will be quite a lot of manual porting, however a c->flash compiler will help a lot. Alchemy looks interesting, I will give it a try... :)

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I suspect that the best you'll be able to achieve will be to isolate and re-use "pure logic" portions of the code that have no user-input or screen-drawing dependencies...